# Public static readonly vs passing a reference

Tags: design-patterns, modeling

For a school project I have to design a system using UML, only I have ran into a problem.

Let's say that I have to design a (somewhat overcomplicated) vending machine. It has a class with the Creator pattern that makes controllers: VendingMachine. This class makes a SaleController object for every sale. The machine supports different kinds of payments, so the SaleController creates a Payment object. The job of this class is to request a payment with the CoinMachine or CardReader classes, based on a user input. However, it obviously needs a reference to the CardReader and CoinMachine objects, which are created by the the VendingMachine class.

Would it be better to create a public static readonly object reference in the VendingMachine? Or to pass an object reference to SaleController and then pass it on to Payment?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a UML task or a coding task? You ask a coding question here, not a UML question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you need a `PaymentService` that is able to encapsulate such logic. This `PaymentService` would be the one deciding whether to use `CardReader` or `CoinMachine` to process the `Payment` object.

`CardReader` and `CoinMachine` should be dependencies of `PaymentService`. If you are using Spring, you could create `CardReader` and `CoinMachine` Beans by annotating them with `@Component` and in `PaymentService` you just need to make them dependencies (injected via `@Autowired` or constructor). If you are not using Spring or any other similar Inversion of Control Framework, your best option would be to create `CardReader` and `CoinMachine` instances on `PaymentService` and keep them as attributes.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I have no idea what Spring or similar is, but the solution at the end is probably the best one. It completely eliminates the need to pass around objects or have public static readonly methods.

Comment: Sorry, I was just giving an example of a technology I am most familiar with, hopping for you to know it as well. But still, as you said the solution holds even without using a Framework such as Spring. If the answer helped you, consider up voting it or even accept it as correct so that others may benefit from it and easily find a solution for similar questions ;)